# How to remap `down` quick open menu in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use `Ctrl+j` for scrolling down the list of suggestions when opening the quick open dialog in vscode. I tried remapping ALL the bindings for `down` to use `Ctrl+j` (I also removed all other bindings for `Ctrl+j`), but it's not working. The `down` arrow is still the only key that moves the selection in that dialog.

How can I fully remap `Ctrl+j` to be `down`? in all aspects of the UI.

Comment: I've made a script to convert all the keybindings to use `HJKL` and friends when using Alt (Ctrl is a bit more tricky imho), so you can look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3v1n0/f5f05005811669d81155abe0826477c8) maybe.

[This](https://gist.github.com/3v1n0/b5f34a4e139d17c9e0d2656a9b9b7fb7) is another similar generated file that includes changes for it. The only case isn't covered by the script is the one handled by @mark's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+j",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
  "when": "inQuickOpen"
}
```

If you don't want the item to be immediately opened, try:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+j",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectNext",
  "when": "inQuickOpen"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+k",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectPrevious",
  "when": "inQuickOpen"
}
```

I just use the Gear Icon/Keyboard Shortcuts to see all available commands.

Also, for discovering commands, see the accepted answer. option 2 at [VSC Command Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453308/vsc-command-log/50777155#50777155)  and my comment thereafter for outputting any commands you execute via the command palette or keybindings.

Comment: Yes! Thank you :). The only small issue with this is that as soon as let go of `ctrl` it immediately selects the file and opens it instead of waiting for me to press `Enter`, but it's something minor. I tried looking for a reference for the actions that are available for mapping and could not find one. How do you discover that these commands exist?

Comment: In some (probably earlier) vscode revisions `"when": "inQuickOpen"` didn't work in all the cases (such as sub-selections), so I had to use instead `"when": "inputFocus && !editorFocus && !findInputFocussed && !findWidgetVisible"`